# PeerId (MCPeerID) customization

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, bluetooth, multipeer-connectivity

I recently have built a fully functional multipeer connectivity app and have had some trouble trying to find a way to allow my users to *change* (or create) a personal **peerId**. The **MCBrowserViewController** picks up devices connected to the same wifi network but only displays their device name and doesn't allow for users to create their own username. How best should I go about this? I have tried **initWithDisplayName()** to no avail and have found no resources pertaining to this written in *Swift* only in Objective-C.

```
import UIKit
import MultipeerConnectivity

class ViewController: UIViewController, MCBrowserViewControllerDelegate, MCSessionDelegate {

let serviceType = "LCOC-Chat"

var browser : MCBrowserViewController!
var assistant : MCAdvertiserAssistant!
var session : MCSession!
var peerID: MCPeerID!

@IBOutlet var chatView: UITextView!
@IBOutlet var messageField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.peerID = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.currentDevice().name)
    self.session = MCSession(peer: peerID)
    self.session.delegate = self

    // create the browser viewcontroller with a unique service name
    self.browser = MCBrowserViewController(serviceType:serviceType,
        session:self.session)

    self.browser.delegate = self;

    self.assistant = MCAdvertiserAssistant(serviceType:serviceType,
        discoveryInfo:nil, session:self.session)

    // tell the assistant to start advertising our fabulous chat
    self.assistant.start()
}

@IBAction func sendChat(sender: UIButton) {
    // Bundle up the text in the message field, and send it off to all
    // connected peers

    let msg = self.messageField.text.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding,
        allowLossyConversion: false)

    var error : NSError?

    self.session.sendData(msg, toPeers: self.session.connectedPeers,
        withMode: MCSessionSendDataMode.Unreliable, error: &error)

    if error != nil {
        print("Error sending data: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
    }

    self.updateChat(self.messageField.text, fromPeer: self.peerID)

    self.messageField.text = ""
}

func updateChat(text : String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
    // Appends some text to the chat view

    // If this peer ID is the local device's peer ID, then show the name 
    // as "Me"
    var name : String

    switch peerID {
    case self.peerID:
        name = "Me"
    default:
        name = peerID.displayName
    }

    // Add the name to the message and display it
    let message = "\(name): \(text)\n"
    self.chatView.text = self.chatView.text + message

}

@IBAction func showBrowser(sender: UIButton) {
    // Show the browser view controller
    self.presentViewController(self.browser, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func browserViewControllerDidFinish(
    browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController!)  {
    // Called when the browser view controller is dismissed (ie the Done 
    // button was tapped)

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

func browserViewControllerWasCancelled(
    browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController!)  {
    // Called when the browser view controller is cancelled

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

func session(session: MCSession!, didReceiveData data: NSData!,
    fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID!)  {
    // Called when a peer sends an NSData to us

    // This needs to run on the main queue
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

        var msg = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        self.updateChat(msg, fromPeer: peerID)
    }
}

// The following methods do nothing, but the MCSessionDelegate protocol 
// requires that we implement them.
func session(session: MCSession!,
    didStartReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String!,
    fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID!, withProgress progress: NSProgress!)  {

    // Called when a peer starts sending a file to us
}

func session(session: MCSession!,
    didFinishReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String!,
    fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID!,
    atURL localURL: NSURL!, withError error: NSError!)  {
    // Called when a file has finished transferring from another peer
}

func session(session: MCSession!, didReceiveStream stream: NSInputStream!,
    withName streamName: String!, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID!)  {
    // Called when a peer establishes a stream with us
}

func session(session: MCSession!, peer peerID: MCPeerID!,
    didChangeState state: MCSessionState)  {
    // Called when a connected peer changes state (for example, goes offline)

    }
 }
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you are creating the local MCPeerID?

Comment: @Paulw11 Just added it to my post, let me know if you have any comments/suggestions pertaining to my question.

Comment: You are using the local device name when you create the local peer. Are you saying that it doesn't work when you use a different string?  Can you show how you tried that?

Comment: I've experimented with it but haven't really found a resolve. Not sure how to, to be honest. @Paulw11

Comment: I haven't had any problem using ` MCPeerID(displayName:"AnyStringYouWant")` although I didn't use `MCBrowserViewController` I just wrote my own using a table view

Comment: Does the table view you wrote segue into the MCBrowserViewController or vice versa? @Paulw11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @paulw11 pointed out above, the reason remote users are seeing only the device name, is because you pass in only the device name in this line of your code:

```
    self.peerID = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.currentDevice().name)
```

For example, if I want my device to show up as Xaphod in someone's else's browser (tableview), then on MY device, the code needs to be:

```
    self.peerID = MCPeerID(displayName: "Xaphod")
```